# .NET 6.0 application some times takes long time to create objects

Tags: c#, .net

We see a strange behaviour in my .NET 6.0 application in my production environment. Shortly described the applications endpoint does the follwoing:

1. Fetches a list of objects from a database
2. Maps the objects from SQLReader to a model (with some custom logic)
3. Returns the list

Seems simple and it runs very fast for the most time being. But some times we see a very long running task between the mapping of SQLReader output to the model class.

The mapping follows this object creation:

```
private static MyCustomObject MapRecord(int indexNo, long id, IDataReader reader)
   return new MyCustomObject(indexNo,
            reader.GetDateTime(DATE),
            id,
            reader.GetString(ID),
            reader.TryRead(TEXT, string.Empty),
            reader.GetDecimal(NUMBER1),
            reader.GetDecimal(NUMBER2),
            reader.TryRead(DATA, string.Empty),
            reader.TryRead(CATEGORY_ID, 0),
            GetCategoryScores(reader.TryRead(CATEGORIES, string.Empty)),
            reader.TryRead<bool?>(SOMEBOOL, null),
            reader.TryRead(SOMEOTHERBOOL, false),
            reader.TryRead(COMMENT, string.Empty),
        );
}
```

At first we suspected the GetCategoryScores, which does a string split in two dimensions:

```
 private static IList<(int, double)>? GetCategoryScores(string? scores)
    {
        if (scores != null)
        {
            return scores.Split(';' , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    var split = x.Split(':');
                    var categoryScore = string.IsNullOrEmpty(split[1]) ? 0 : double.Parse(split[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    return (int.Parse(split[0]), categoryScore);
                }).ToList();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My Jaeger traces showed that, it was NOT the case, hence i can only see the "TryRead" function to be the sinner. It looks like this:

```
 public static T? TryRead<T>(this IDataReader reader, int ordinal, T? defaultOnNull) =>
        reader.IsDBNull(ordinal)
            ? defaultOnNull
            : (T)reader[ordinal];
```

My other suspicion is that it is when the GC collects unused objects, it takes time. Usually the execution time of the MapRecord function is negligible, but when it takes time it takes between 1s and 1.5s.
The application is deployed as a docker container and runs on a kubernetes cluster.

Has anyone seen anything like this before and have any suggestions of what to do?

Comment: Are you using a big number of Tasks to perform these operations?

Comment: Is a task per row (100 in most cases) a lot? I create one per sql row.

Comment: `using var reader = await conn.ExecuteReaderAsync(rawSql, parameters).ConfigureAwait(false);`
`while (reader.Read()) yield return reader;`

And then used with

`await foreach (var reader in _executor.ExecuteReaderAsync(scope.HostRealmId, template.RawSql, template.Parameters).ConfigureAwait(false))`

Answer (score 0):

If it's not GC, my guess is that it's the reader having to wait for data being streamed back from the database, most likely because other queries are locking tables and delaying the result, but maybe also due to general CPU/disk contention or networking issues.

Comment: So even though it could look like the querying in the database in my tracing tool looks fine, it is not the same as fetching the data?

Comment: Querying is separated into executing the query and then streaming the results. I am not an expert on exactly how this process works, but I know that it happens on demand as you fetch data. If you fetch enough data to empty the reader's buffer and the reader has to synchronously wait around for more data, it will look like that reader method is taking a long time because it's sitting there waiting, and that's basically the symptom you're seeing.

Comment: Okay. The strange part is that it only happens some times and not at the same rows every time (probably due to what is loaded in memory). And i can see no pattern at all in what rows are slower than others.

Comment: Combined with PMF's comment - if the reader (or indeed something else) is synchronously waiting, and enough instances of the whole operation happens in parallel, you could end up blocking all threads in the thread pool used to run the task, which would give a noticeable pause until the thread pool injects another thread to make it possible for tasks to keep running. [This article is a good read on the subject](https://www.poppastring.com/blog/inducing-and-measuring-threadpool-exhaustion) and seeing what the counters return during a slowdown is probably very instructive.

Comment: Not seeing a pattern in the rows/data is reasonable - it's more about the total load placed on the database (or whichever resource is running up against a limit). No individual rock causes the landslide.

Comment: The threadpool problem was what I was referring to yes. We have seen that extending the thread pool can take a second or so, so it's important to stay below its limit or control its size manually.

Comment: I am deploying in Kubernetes. Would you believe scaling to more pods that would distribute the load could help this?

Comment: I have way too little information to say that. Finding out the root issue will help - if it's thread pool exhaustion, spreading the load of your program (or being smarter about not filling the pool up, if possible) would help, but if it's contention on the road to or in the database, that's where you'd have to look. Or it could be something completely different.

Comment: I tried scaling the application and that slowed the application even more down.
It looks lige congestion towards the database or GC.

Comment: That sounds like database congestion then, since the database is hit with more traffic (or at least can now be hit with more traffic). I would look into how the other queries against the same table look. If they take a lock on the table during a long operation, that holds up any query, no matter how innocent. It's worth logging the IDs to the query too, to see if the same ID always causes the issue - if not, it's other things than your own operation causing it.